# Why does the array reference number switch to a STRING?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I found the problem I was having with referencing but I don't understand what's happening now. The array is being populated properly but I couldn't figure out why I couldn't pull the values. Then after some trial and error I found at the end if I closed the array reference value in quotes it would return the right value. Why is the reference being turned into a string when it's created using an integer?

```
    function initPPArray(year) {
  var beginningOfYear = new Date('January 1, 2014');
  var dayOffset = (beginningOfYear.getDay() + 6) % 7;

  var beginningOfPP = new Date(beginningOfYear.getFullYear(), beginningOfYear.getMonth(), beginningOfYear.getDate() - dayOffset);
  var payPeriodList = [];
  payPeriodList[1] = {};
  payPeriodList[1].start = beginningOfPP;
  payPeriodList[1].end = new Date(beginningOfPP.getFullYear(), beginningOfPP.getMonth(), beginningOfPP.getDate() + 13);
  Logger.log('beginningOfPP: ' + beginningOfPP);

  var txtStart = getMonthString(payPeriodList[1].start) + ", " + payPeriodList[1].start.getDate();
  var txtEnd = getMonthString(payPeriodList[1].end) + ", " + payPeriodList[1].end.getDate();
  Logger.log("PP 1: " + txtStart + " - " + txtEnd);
  for (var i = 2; i <= 26; i++) {
    payPeriodList[i] = {};
    payPeriodList[i].start = new Date(payPeriodList[i-1].end.getFullYear(), payPeriodList[i-1].end.getMonth(), payPeriodList[i-1].end.getDate() + 1);
    payPeriodList[i].end = new Date(payPeriodList[i].start.getFullYear(), payPeriodList[i].start.getMonth(), payPeriodList[i].start.getDate() + 13);
    var txtStart = getMonthString(payPeriodList[i].start) + ", " + payPeriodList[i].start.getDate();
    var txtEnd = getMonthString(payPeriodList[i].end) + ", " + payPeriodList[i].end.getDate();
    Logger.log("PP: " + i + ": " + txtStart + " - " + txtEnd);
  }
  // This returns the proper value.. when no quotes are used it returns  
  // the last date of the loop "Dec 15,2014"
  Logger.log("Random Value: " + payPeriodList["6"].start)
  return payPeriodList;
}
```

Comment: Not what you are asking about, but you could replace that 23-line `switch` statement with one line: `var dayOffset = (beginningOfYear.getDay() + 6) % 7;`

Comment: certainly useful. Thanks for the tip. This is my first programming project and everything is self-taught. I will take any advice I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in JavaScript start with index `0`, not index `1`. So this code:

```
var payPeriodList = new Array();
payPeriodList[1] = {
    // ...
};
```

...leaves the `0th` entry blank while making the array's length `2` (because standard JavaScript arrays are inherently sparse, as they [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html)). Once you've done that, since you're using `push` in the subsequent code, that first entry is never filled in.

Change the `1` to a `0`, or use `push` for the first entry (as you are with the subsequent ones).

---

Side note: It's almost always better to create an array with an array literal, not `new Array()`:

```
var payPeriodList = [];
```

Comment: I used Array literals but through searching SO I tried several variations. I'll try cleaning up the code and using your recommendations. I was starting payPeriodList at "1" since I was going to use the index as the corresponding payPeriod number.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that every item in your payPeriodList array is a reference to the same object (payPeriodItem). Each iteration through your assignment array is altering the start and end values of payPeriodItem instead of creating a new object with new start and end values. So to solve this, you would need only change the first line inside the for loop to assign a new object to payPeriodList[i].

```
for (var i = 2; i <= 26; i++) {
    payPeriodList[i] = {};
    /*...*/
}
```

Comment: That gives me the same result. The array is populating okay, I just don't know why the array index has become a string. I can only recall a value if I do: payPeriodList("6")

Comment: Are you sure the array is populating OK? I've copied your code and put console.log(payPeriodList["6"] === payPeriodList[6]) before the return statement and it evaluates to true. I don't know why one can access the array element with the stringed int, but I don't see how you can be getting different values for the two.

Comment: This works now.. I don't get it. I was stumped on this for hours last night and I could not get the proper value unless the array index was a string. Your suggestion works fine, and I reverted back to the original which is also working fine. Wtf?